# Bug using webpack-dev-server

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to compile this command

```
npm run dev-server
```

I have these files 
**index.js**

```
import otherSquare, { addNumber, name } from './utilities';
import otherScream from './scream';

console.log('index.js');
console.log(addNumber(30, 3));
console.log(name);
console.log(otherScream(name));
console.log(otherSquare(10));
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/scripts'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['env']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        publicPath: '/scripts/'
    }
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "boilerplate",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "input.js",
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        "live-server": "^1.2.1",
        "webpack": "^4.5.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^2.0.14"
    }
}
```

When I run the command line down below

```
npm run dev-server
```

My site is working, when I save some file, it refresh on the page, but when I open the browser console, it appears this error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOpOw.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this command line in the terminal

```
npm install webpack@latest webpack-cli@latest webpack-dev-server@latest
```

And now worked it